# How do I add a scrollable set of images in Word 2016?

Tags: html, word-2016

I would like to know how to add a set of images in Word and make them scrollable in some kind of viewing pane. I have tried to add a frame, but I can't enable the scroll bars if add pictures to it. The document will be saved as an html file and used as a WebQuest project for one of my education classes.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please show your work, it would help this community to serve you

Comment: What makes you think this is possible? Word is primarily a word processor, not a web authoring tool.

Comment: @NIMISHAN I would not know how to do that, I am sorry

Comment: @duskwuff I was asking to know how to do it, if possible. I am not a programmer, so I apologize for any deficiencies